# Load CSV in HTML auto load the same file

Tags: javascript, html, csv

The above "html" code to chose CSV file and load
but is there any way to change to auto load allways the same CSV file when Refresh
C:\File.csv

```
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var datasource = document.getElementById('datasource');
            datasource.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                var csvFile = datasource.files[0];
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    var table = document.getElementById('table');
                    var lines = fileReader.result.split(/\r?\n/);
                    var n = 0;
                    lines.forEach(function (line) {
                        n++;
                        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                        tr.setAttribute("class", "row");
                        tr.setAttribute("id", "row_" + n);
                        var cells = line.split(/,/);
                        var m = 0;
                        cells.forEach(function (cell) {
                            var td = document.createElement("td");
                            m++;
                            td.setAttribute("id", "cell_" + n + "-" + m);
                            td.setAttribute("class", "cell");
                            var text = document.createTextNode(cell);
                            td.appendChild(text);
                            tr.appendChild(td);
                        });
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                    });
                }
                fileReader.readAsText(csvFile);
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
```

```
Select CSV file:
<input type="file" id="datasource" />
<div>Table with loaded CSV file:</div>
<table id="table" class=table></table>
```

The above "html" code to chose CSV file and load
but is there any way to change to auto load allways the same CSV file when Refresh
C:\File.csv

Comment: You tagged your question with "java" but there is no Java code. I can see only JavaScript code. Java and JavaScript are fundamental different languages.

Comment: i change it o javascript

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; No, It is not possible.

A webpage cannot just choose to read any file from the user's computer, the browser would not allow it as that would be a security nightmare. The browser will only allow you to access file(s) that are either selected from the file input popup or dropped onto an file input.